# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer uma simples inserção no banco de dados, como já fiz várias vezes, usando PDO e não consigo! O que tem de errado?

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$opcao = $data->opcao;
$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;
$nome = $data->nome;
$usuario = $data->user;
$idempresa = $data->idempresa;

$insereUsuario=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (idusuario, usuario, senha, email, empresa_idempresa, nome)
                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereUsuario->bindValue(1, NULL);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(2, $usuario);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(3, $senha);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(4, $email);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(5, $idempresa);
$insereUsuario->bindValue(6, $nome);
$insereUsuario->execute();
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idusuario' cannot be null'

Minha tabela no BD
[image: table usuario]

Comment: Provavelmente o id da empresa informado não existe na tabela de empresas.

Comment: você esta fazendo uma inserção e o `idusuario` não pode ser NULL, (vazio)

Comment: Pelo que chequei, anteriormente, o id da empresa está vindo sim.
Sim, eu entendo que o idusuario não pode ser null... Normal. Mas veja o meu comando de inserção! Não tem nada errado! Não está null

Comment: A chave primaria é o `idUsuario` e `empresa_idempresa`?